# Controlling spacing under Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get rid of the spacing between my input and the buttons to the right of it. Usually, the last resort is to override all the styles by adding an inline style in the tag, overriding everything else. However, I noticed that (a) it doesn't seem to affect the page and (b) the spacing actually gets bigger for smaller screen width.

My conclusion based on that (and some googlearch) is that Bootstrap uses JavaScript to dynamically set the styles to adapt to screens of different sizes. That's great but it gives me only limited control over how the controls are placed.

I'm guessing it's an awesome feature generally speaking but at the moment I'm only interested in Bootstrap's looks, not the layouting. How do I effectively override that? In the future I'll need to apply the layouting so I can't just remove it.

```
<div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-5 "
     style="border: solid red 1px;" 
     data-date-format="dd M 'yy - hh:ii" 
     data-link-field="myDate">
  <input class="form-control" 
         style="border: solid yellow 1px;" 
         size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
  <span class="input-group-addon" style="border: solid blue 1px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove " 
          style="border: blueviolet 10px;">
    </span>
  </span>
  <span class="input-group-addon" style="border: solid orange 1px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th" 
          style="border: solid orangered 1px;"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="myDate" value="" />
```

The actual question is how to in the above markup deactivate/override the spacing between input and spans without removing Bootstrap.

Could it be as easy as alternating one of the classes? I've read on some guides but wasn't enlighten, exactly. Likely **not** because of the docs being wrong, hehe.

Comment: `display: inline` elements problem?

Comment: Bootstrap uses [`media queries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to adapt styles, not JS. Don't use inline-styles to override. Though Bootstrap goes against a common best practice of not using `!important` for their style properties, the Bootstrap team has the proper experience and good reasons for when and why they use it. Using `!important` will override inline styles. So basically don't use inline styles and don't use `!important` unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Are you using external stylesheet, if yes, have you put the link of the stylesheet after the Bootstrap's stylesheet? Have you tried using CSS [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) rules?

Comment: Are you asking to remove the padding from the `.input-group-addon` elements? A simple graphic showing what your objective is would be very helpful. If the graphic compared _"this (want) vs this (don't want)"_ would be great. My interpretation of what you're trying to achieve [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/t06t8mzx/).

Comment: @hungerstar Media queries are all new to me. I've seen something like that years ago and never touched it in any production environment. Awesome link, which I think you should post as a reply. Totally acceptable as an answer. I also have a follow up question but I'll delay it until the answer's been provided. Your quess of *wants-vs-gets* was almost spot on too. Awesome!

Comment: @Aakash I'm not sure how that relates to the code example I've posted. As you can see, I'm setting style directly in the tag and **still** get no control over the behavior of layout.

Comment: @KonradViltersten the specificity of a rule will determine if it's properties get applied or not. If you have `<div class="a-style" style="color: red;">` and the following style `.a-style { color: blue !important; }` the text will be blue and not red. The `!important` statement is the only way to increase a CSS selector's specificity to the point it can override inline styles. This may be what you're seeing with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the issuing you are experiencing is the use of [`media queries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) in Bootstrap that control the style of various elements. That is why they get wider on smaller screens. Media queries are a CSS feature.

The likely reason that your inline styles are not working is because Bootstrap uses `!important` statements.

**NOTE:** Please don't interpret Bootstrap's use of `!important` as a sign to use `!important` *carte blanche* yourself. It is considered against best practice to use `!important` when ever you feel like it. [Specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/) should be used before `!important`. Once one has gained enough experience, as the Bootstrap team likely has, then you'll know when it is *acceptable* to use `!important` or not.

As for the spacing between input elements and spans I'm not exactly clear on what that is. I take it as you want to remove some of the padding on the spans around the `glyphicon` spans.

Something like:

```css
.input-group-addon {
    padding: 6px 0;
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t06t8mzx/).